# How to update second record after updating the first record in an ArrayList

Tags: android, service

In my Android Application i have `Two Activities`, in my first `Activity` is contains List of tickets with TicketId and `Update button` Here When Click i the update button then it will will go to `Activity2` and there is text field to update data and button for submit. when i click that button the data was updated and again it come back to `Activity1`.
   Here is my main problem When i click update button of anther record my App closing with unfortunatly stopped Error below is my code.

**here is my First Activity:**

```
       public void loadHeroList() {

        //getting the progressbar
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        //making the progressbar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://182.18.163.39/train/m/list_details.php?username="+user+"&key="+pass,
                new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //hiding the progressbar after completion
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = jsonobject.getString("Sno");
                                String Tktid = jsonobject.getString("TKTID");
                                link = jsonobject.getString("Link");
                                status = jsonobject.getString("Status");

                                List list = new List(user, pass, jsonobject.getString("Sno"), jsonobject.getString("TKTID"),jsonobject.getString("Link"),jsonobject.getString("Status"));
                                tktList.add(list);

                                Log.i("website content", name);
                                Log.i("website content", Tktid);
                                Log.i("website content", link);

                            }

                            //creating custom adapter object
                            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(tktList, getApplicationContext());

                            //adding the adapter to listview
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//                            adapter = (ListViewAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
//                            List item = adapter.getItem(0);
//                            adapter.remove(item);
//                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

**List Adapter:**

```
 final Button btupdate = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btupdate);
//        Button btview = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btview);
        final List hero = tktList.get(position);

        btupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, Main2Activity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                i.putExtra("Link", hero.getLink());
                i.putExtra("Status", hero.getStatus());
                i.putExtra("username", hero.getUsername());
                i.putExtra("password", hero.getPassword());
                mCtx.startActivity(i);

            }

        });

        //Getting the hero for the specified position
        //setting hero values to textviews
        textViewName.setText(hero.getSno());
        textViewImageUrl.setText(hero.getTktid());
        //returning the listitem


        return listViewItem;
    }
```

**And my Second Activity:**

```
  btnupdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnupdate);

        btnupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etupdate = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextUpdate)).getText().toString();
                action = etupdate;

                ticketid = message;

                if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Pending")) {

                    try {
                        action = URLEncoder.encode(action,"UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        int l = etupdate.length();
                        if (l != 0) {
                            url = "http://182.18.163.39/train/m/action.php?username=" + username + "&key=" + password + "&tktid=" + ticketid + "==&action=" + action;
                        } else
                            url = "http://182.18.163.39/train/m/action.php?username=" + username + "&key=" + password + "&tktid=" + ticketid + "==&action=";

                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(responseString);
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
                        jsonObj.put("Result", jsonarray);
                        String msg = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Result").getJSONObject(0).getString("Error");

                        String Successmsg = "Deficiency updated successfully.";

                        if (msg.equalsIgnoreCase(Successmsg)) {

                            onUpdatePressed(view);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed to update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already updated you are not allow to update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void onUpdatePressed(View view) {

//        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
//        i.putExtra("UserName",username);
//        i.putExtra("PassWord",password);
//        startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
        m.loadHeroList();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

here is my Error log:

```
03-08 11:10:36.902 9886-9886/com.example.lenovo.trainapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.lenovo.trainapp, PID: 9886
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lenovo.trainapp/com.example.lenovo.trainapp.Main3Activity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                               at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                               at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
                                                                               at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
                                                                               at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                                                                               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                                                                               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
                                                                               at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
                                                                               at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
                                                                               at com.example.lenovo.trainapp.Main3Activity.onCreate(Main3Activity.java:73)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: I posted my Error log

Comment: The error says unable to start {Main3Activity}. Perhaps you forgot to mention this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: The other thing in the error is {android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException}. Are you loading your data in the UI thread? It seems you do in your second activity.

Comment: For first time my Activiy3 is opening when try to open second time it is giving that Error

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your webservice call in async task

put the below code in doInBackground

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot make network request using main thread. you must wrap you network calls on a background task e.g. Asynctask and just use interface callback to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

main activity in onResume method called like below code ..

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadHeroList();
}
```

and remove code in onUpdatePressed method like below

```
 MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
    m.loadHeroList();
```

only call super.onBackPresss then it call first activity in onResume method

Comment: But it is giving duplicates for my records for the first time opening of my list activity

Comment: check  m.loadHeroList(); is calling onCreate method or not if is calling oncreate method then remove it.

Comment: it's working good if i remove both onResume and m.loadHeroList() methods. but here another problem is which record i updated that is also displaying but i want to remove which record is updated can u please help me

Comment: you make changes in server response it give only not update record other wise you can manage arraylist remove update record that time you can get item position and remove from the list and set fresh array list data.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove update data from the list when you click on btnUpdate like below ..

```
       tktList.remove(tktList.indexOf(hero));
```

then after notify adapter.